# Node.js promisses chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is the following code:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res) {
  models.Task.find(req.params.id).then(function(task) {
    task.updateAttributes({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description
    }).then(function(task) {
      res.json(task);
    })
  });
});
```

I'm trying to re-factor this code following way:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res) {
  models.Task.find(req.params.id).then(function(task) {
    task.updateAttributes({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description
    })
  }).then(function(task) {
    res.json(task);
  });
});
```

In the first case I can see correct JSON output, but in the second can I see empty output. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not waiting for `updateAttributes` to complete anymore. You can do, though, by just adding a `return`:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res) {
  models.Task.find(req.params.id).then(function(task) {
    return task.updateAttributes({
//  ^^^^^^
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description
    });
  }).then(function(task) {
    res.json(task);
  });
});
```

When you return a promise from an earlier handler in the chain, subsequent handlers wait for it (and receive its resolution value).

---

Side note: Remember to handle failures in promises, too, by using the second argument to `then` and/or using `catch`.

Comment: Please, tell me, how can I check if task is not null for updating attributes? Thanks!

Comment: @malcoauri: *Can* `task` be `null`? (I'm not familiar with the lib in question, but I would expect that to reject the promise rather than resolve it with `null`.) If so, a simple `if (task == null)` should be sufficient. In which case you'd probably `return task` rather than returning the promise from `task.updateAttributes`. Subsequent `then` handlers will get `null` (immediately).

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the 2nd promise:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res) {
  models.Task.find(req.params.id).then(function(task) {
    return task.updateAttributes({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description
    });
  }).then(function(task) {
    res.json(task);
  });
});
```